# Is matrix $AA^T + tI$ always regular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Is $AA^T + tI$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $t > 0$, always regular for arbitrary $A$ and $t$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You've asked a sensible mathematical question, but you provided no context.  Did this come up in the solution of a larger problem, or was it a standalone assigned exercise?  Providing context, such as showing you approached the problem from some basic idea (e.g. applying the definition), will not only help Readers respond in a useful way now, it will help future Readers benefit from your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider the quadratic form
$$\langle(AA^T + tI)x,x\rangle = \|A^Tx\|^2 + t \|x\|^2$$ you obverse that it the quadratic form is strictly positive for all $x \neq 0$. Therefore the Matrix
$AA^T + tI$ has only positive eigenvalues which gives that the matrix is regular.